# How can I automatically reboot machine after usb pull off?

Tags: boot, usb, scripts, init.d

I have this situation - I've got a boot-able pen-drive with Ubuntu 12.04 for automated installation - when I plug the USB stick in installation begins from it. At the end of installation process I want to put a message on screen to user to pull out the USB stick - because else the installation will be committed again and again after reboot.

So the case is to automatically reboots the machine after the message is shown and pendrive is pulled off from machine.

Any ideas how to achieve this ?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=119111)